# convert the values if it falls between specific number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to convert the values if it falls between specific number then convert them into specific number.

For Example

```
IF(AND(Cell>0.0, Cell<=0.25),0.25,"")
IF(AND(Cell>0.25, Cell<=0.50),0.50,"")
IF(AND(Cell>0.50, Cell<=0.75),0.75,"")
IF(AND(Cell>0.75, Cell<=1.0),1.0,"")
```

Is it possible to convert the values into given values i would appreciate your help thanks.

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LK4kOMav8FRnrMG6QFfLSZEfsHSjlcKSrUcgyloMO6M/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***updated answer:***

```
=index(ceiling(A2:A22,0.25))
```

**Alternative:**

```
=index(lambda(z,xlookup(A2:A22,z,z,,1))({0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much but it should work for nth range. I could not elaborate it well. Let me explain it what if i add the value like 9.45, will it convert into 9.50.

Comment: in that case you may want to just use `=index(ceiling(A2:A22,0.25))`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the solution in your sheet. You need to nest the if statements like this:

```
=IF(AND(A3>0,A3<=0.25), 0.25, IF(AND(A3>0.25,A3<=0.5), 0.5, IF(AND(A3>0.5,A3<=0.75), 0.75, IF(AND(A3>0.75,A3<=1), 1))))
```

It looks a bit messy but it works. I don't know what you wanted to be the result if the value was over 1 though...

The IF function works like this:

```
IF(statement, if it's true, if it's false)
```

So just check if it is between one interval, and then if it isn't then you check another interval.

Hope this helps:)